# static_cast_tag() substitute in latest boost version

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I see `static_cast_tag()` was supported and earlier version of boost C++ (1.47 and before) under [boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) but in latest boost versions this is missing from shared_ptr.hpp file ([see](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp)). Under which file this functionality is been kept? Is this syntax used any longer or scrapped in new versions of boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_cast_tag` is an implementation detail of how Boost 1.47 implements `static_pointer_cast` (hence its location in a `detail` namespace).

You should be using [`static_pointer_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#functions) directly; this will work with all Boost versions.